# How can I swap resources for different versions of an application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I developing an application which will have at least 2 if not 3-4 different versions (don't ask). The applications will basically be identical except have different product names, window titles, application icon and some other minor differences in string or image resources.

My main goal is to avoid having to create multiple projects for each executable. I want to be able to have one main application project and have it just load those resources (name, icon, etc.) and be agnostic of which version it is. This way, I can simply configure my setup project to deploy the proper resources with the version of that application. Ideally it would not be that visible to the end-user after it was installed.

What I've tried: I've experimented with creating different .resx files and swapping them based off build configuration, or I've also experimented with adding environment variables and #if on the variable. **But, I really do not want multiple build configurations.** I want it to only depend on deployment.

Is it possible to create resx files, either in a different project or in the same project and exclude them from the build, and have them generated into satellite .DLL assemblies similar to localization, and then load whichever one is deployed with the application?

I'm confused if I should be looking at running my own RESGEN and AL tasks, or if I should just create a DLL project (but maybe then I'd have to have multiple DLL projects for only 1 resource file). Also, any article I can find about using .RESX files is for localization. It relies on setting the CurrentCulture to resolve the specific resources to use. My scenario has nothing to do with culture... **I just want to load different resources for different deployments of the application.**

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how deeply you need to go, you can package the resources into separate .dll files and differentiate that way. For instance, building the various different versions into a seperate DLLs and having your installer adjust the name to match what your application expects or use an XML configuration file to specify which to load and load it that way.

[Assembly.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will allow you to load the alternative assembly.

```
Assembly _assembly;
_assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

Stream _imageStream;
_imageStream = 
    _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
    "ThumbnailPictureViewer.resources.Image1.bmp");
Bitmap theDefaultImage = new Bitmap(_imageStream);
```

See: http://www.attilan.com/2006/08/accessing-embedded-resources-using.html

Comment: Yeah... this is probably where I was going too... I wonder how this would effect localization if we needed to do that in the future. I'm debating how to create those assemblies that have the resources.